# Matlab - Interpolation of shear from scattered data

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Sorry for the title, didn't really know how to explain it well.
So here is the situation,
I have coordinate points in a 3D space and each point has a given shear. I need to interpolate the shear for points I don't have(obviously).As a heads up the data is non-monotonic.

Here is what I have so far:

```
m=xlsread('innerwall-mesh1.csv');
x=m(:,1);
y=m(:,2);
z=m(:,3);
xs=m(:,5);
xq=linspace(.0329,.0199,10);
yq=linspace(.0142,.0207,10);
zq=linspace(.0046,.0046,10);
[xn,yn,zn]=meshgrid(xq,yq,zq);
F=scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z,xs);
xsn=F(xn,yn,zn);
surf(xn,yn,zn,xsn)
```

Now the problem is I get an empty matrix for the interpolated shear. Can anyone guide me in the right direction. Thank you for all the help. Cheers.

UPDATE: Ok so I decided to use a second set of data, which would be my second timestep. And in this case I do get a value for xsn, so my guess is that it doesn't want to interpolate because z is constant for all points. But I still get a surf error, "XData must be a vector or 2D array". No idea what to do. Any suggestions?

FINAL UPDATE: So I ended up just interpolating z and shear using x and y. This worked wonderfully, don't know why I didn't think of it earlier. When compared to scatter data, it looks very well. Thanks for all who tried!!

Comment: I don't see anything fundamentally wrong here. Have you verified that `x`, `y`, `z` and `xs` actually contain the data you expect?

Comment: Yep, just checked they are all fine. zq is correct, at least that's what i need it to be. So this is a "flap" and in the first time step it is flat.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalezJimenez and just to confirm, you are saying that `numel(xsn) == 0`?